# How do you copy response values to the clipboard in Postman javascript tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, postman

I've recently found out about the ability in postman to write pre-request and test scripts using javascript.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to copy a value to the clipboard during a test in conjunction with setting the postman environment variable.

For example:

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable ("Action ID", jsonData.ActionId);
// set jsonData.ActionId to clipboard
```

Comment: The most basic and simple answer is...no. There is some magic in the visualizer you could do to get a value to copy to the clipboard but that's about it and that would also happen after the request.

Comment: why you want to do it ?

Comment: I have a project that requires me to constantly grab ID values generated by API calls through postman. Currently I spend a lot of time running the action and then copy pasting it elsewhere.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is a way that it could be achieved, by using the visualizer and bringing in the `clipboard.js` CDN.

This is very basic but by adding this script to the `Tests` tab, you can see the variable value in the `Visualize` tab, in the response section.

```
pm.environment.set("Action_ID", pm.response.json().ActionId);

let template = `
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div>
        <pre><code style="width:max-content!important;" id="copyText">${pm.environment.get('Action_ID')}</code></pre>
    </div>
    <button class="copyButton" type="button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copyText" style="background:green;color:white;">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.copyButton');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        e.clearSelection();
        e.trigger.textContent = '✔ Copied!';
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy to Clipboard';
        }, 2000);
    });
    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        e.clearSelection();
        e.trigger.textContent = '✗ Not Copied';
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy to Clipboard';
        }, 2000);
    });

</script>`

pm.visualizer.set(template, pm.response.json())
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's really interesting I hadn't thought about an approach like that. Thank you

Comment: Brilliant man - I was using a Postman Tests tab to output to console so I could grab it from there, but was getting tired of having to select the value from there.

Answer (score 10):

@Danny Dainton
That's super clever solution. Thank you!

Here's a simplier version with auto-copy. No need to click on the button manually.

```
const response = pm.response.json();

let template = `<html><body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.11/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <code style="width:max-content!important;padding:10px;display:block;" id="copyText">${response.token}</code>
    <button id="copyButton" type="button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#copyText" style="background:green;color:white;">Copy to Clipboard</button>
    <script>
        new ClipboardJS('#copyButton')
            .on('success', function(e) {
                e.clearSelection();
            })
            .on('error', function(e) {
                e.clearSelection();
                copyText.style.borderColor = 'red';
            });
        copyButton.click();
    </script>
</body></html>`;

pm.visualizer.set(template);
```

Comment: This did what I needed it to do - auto copy to clipboard. Thanks! Maybe wrap it in a function that users can dump into their Tests tab.

Comment: This should use `<pre>` tags instead of `<code>` to retain newlines.

Comment: Also, just a note: the `copyButton.click();` automatic copy requires the Visualize tab be open or opened, ie. it's triggered when the Visualize tab loads.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample without using any CDN or library.

```
let template =
`    
    <script>
        pm.getData(function (error, data)
        {
            let textBox = document.createElement('textarea');
            textBox.value = data.key;
            document.body.appendChild(textBox);
            textBox.focus();
            textBox.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(textBox);
        });
    </script>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, 
    pm.response.json()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to copy the console output.  This is not a programmatic solution but it is easy to do.

First open the Postman Console (click on the small icon at the bottom left).

[image]

Then click "Clear" at the top right corner of the Console.  This will clear out existing console data from prior requests.  It's best if this is cleared out so that when you copy the data that you want to copy it will include only the newly generated requests.

Next process your requests. Each request should appear as a new line in the console.

Then click the copy icon.

All of the request data, including responses, will be saved on your clipboard.  Response lines all start with "Response Body:".  You can then parse the text in Excel or elsewhere.

[image]